# Validate dynamic input field in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a table in which I add the input field dynamically and I set the validation manually by using Toastr notifications . what the problem is that  when I add the input at the first time the validation is working perfectly but when I add another input the validation is not working on new added input. I have tried and searched for the solution but I did not find any solution.Any help will be highly appreciated.

**My HTML code :**

```html
<table class="table-hover" id="form">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>پلورنکی</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(row, $index) in rows" :key="row.id">
      <td>
        <input
          dir="rtl"
          id="supplier_id1"
          v-model="row.supplier_id1"
          placeholder="نیټه "
          type="text"
          name="supplier_id1"
          class="form-control"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button
  class="btn btn-success btn-xs"
  @click="getData()"
>
  خوندی کړی
</button>
```

**My script code :**

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      rows: [
        {
          supplier_id1: "",
         }
      ],
    }
  }
  methods: {
    getData: function() {
      if (this.rows[0].supplier_id1 == "") {
        toast.fire({
          icon: "warning",
          html: "<h5> supplier id is required.</h5>"
        });
      } else {
        //if the input is not emptyexecute the coed successfully 
      }                
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always check for the first row, because of `if (this.rows[0]...)`
`rows[0]` will always take the first object in your array

If you always want to validate all the rows, you could check if there are any rows without a supplier id: `if (this.rows.filter((row) => row.supplier_id1 === "").length)`

Answer (score 0):

I not sure which toast component did you used, but i can do similar mock for your validation message + databinding of your `{{row.supplier_id1}}`

`v-model` value of `input[type="date]` will only valid when you inputted date correctly so `this.rows[0].supplier_id1.length == 0` to validate is fine. The reactivity is working fine.

My Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bu9twps2/

UPDATE: Your original condition to validate works fine as well, problem likely lies at your `toast`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, there is no problem in the toast. The problem is when I add new row the validation is not being applied on second row

Comment: if you're trying to do validation with 1 button for >1 rows, your method needed to be updated with `this.rows[1]....this.rows[2]` etc. Suggest use `v-for` loop for list rendering and update validate method to check each row.